# django-tables2 updating attrs has no effect

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-tables2

I am using django + django-tables2.  I want to add to each column of my tables a td-level attribute which contains its name (for later client side processing).  The tables are based on models and aren't built column by column. Hence I don't have an opportunity to supply these attributes at the time I define the table.

I am trying to inject the attributes at a later stage using this piece of code:

```
def inject_data_names(table: tables.Table) -> tables.Table:
    for col_name, col in table.columns.items():
        col.attrs['td']['data'] = str(col_name)
        print(col.attrs)
    return table
```

However, it seems to have no effect, when run on an instance of a child of tables.Table.  The print statement shows this:

```
{'class': 'paleblue table', 'th': {'class': 'id orderable'}, 'td': {'class': 'id'}}
{'class': 'paleblue table', 'th': {'class': 'description orderable'}, 'td': {'class': 'description'}}
{'class': 'paleblue table', 'th': {'class': 'orderable start'}, 'td': {'class': 'start'}}
```

As you can see, the "data" value seems to be missing.  Using Python 3.6.1, latest Django and django-tables2.  Any clues?

**UPD:** Looking at the source code, the method attrs in BoundColumn actually returns a copy of the dictionary, hence the update has no effect.  The question is, what's the right way of making the changes I want?

Link: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_tables2/columns/base.html#BoundColumn

Comment: Why do you have to update attrs after the table is initialized?

Comment: My tables are based on models and aren't built column by column.  Hence I don't have an opportunity to supply these attributes at the time I define the table.  Nonetheless, I want to add to each column a td attribute which contains its name (for later client side processing).

Comment: That makes sense. Interesting use case, I cannot think of straightforward way to add attrs to existing columns... Can you open an issue in the Github repo, I'll see if we can make that possible, or if it is already possible, we can  add documentation.

Comment: I have posted an answer with a hacky solution.  It works, but I'm not sure it will in the future, so I'll add an issue as you suggest, linking it to this discussion.

Comment: My hack doesn't actually seem to work, unfortunately, so I have removed the answer.  Thus the question still remains open.

For those who are interested in following the issue, this is the link: https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/451

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the developers of the library, there is now a working solution to my problem.  It requires the version 1.9.0 or later of the package:

```
class Table(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        attrs = {
           'td': {'data-name': lambda column: column.name}
        }
```

Further discussion on github: https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/451

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with django-tables but I found that somebody recently added this feature to the library:

https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/70

this is the testcase for the commit that adds the feature to dynamically add columns: [github link](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/817d7113fcf50db85e5d2a0700bdfb197f2ab781/tests/test_dynamically_add_columns.py)

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import django_tables2 as tables


def test_dynamically_adding_columns():
    '''
    When adding columns to self.base_columns, they are actually added to
    the class attribute `Table.base_columns`, and not to the instance
    attribute, `table.base_columns`
    issue #403
    '''
    data = [
        {'name': 'Adrian', 'country': 'Australia'},
        {'name': 'Adrian', 'country': 'Brazil'},
        {'name': 'Audrey', 'country': 'Chile'},
        {'name': 'Bassie', 'country': 'Belgium'},
    ]

    class MyTable(tables.Table):
        name = tables.Column()

    # this is obvious:
    assert list(MyTable(data).columns.columns.keys()) == ['name']

    assert list(MyTable(data, extra_columns=[
        ('country', tables.Column())
    ]).columns.columns.keys()) == ['name', 'country']

    # this new instance should not have the extra columns added to the first instance.
    assert list(MyTable(data).columns.columns.keys()) == ['name']
```

Comment: Right, and how does that help me to add attributes to an existing column?